# Unable to insert records into redis using redis-om-spring library

Tags: spring, redis, redis-om-spring

Please help me on the below scenario.

I have redis docker container running in redis://default:redispw@localhost:49153

and I'm trying to execute the code from below repository with appropriate properties

https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/tree/main/demos/roms-permits

Properties in application.properites

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.username=default
spring.redis.password=redispw
spring.redis.port=49153
```

While executing the code, I'm getting the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.redis.om.permits.PermitsApplication.main(PermitsApplication.java:94) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command 'FT.DROP', with args beginning with: 'com.redis.om.permits.models.PermitIdx' 
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:142) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:176) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:230) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:352) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:270) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
    at io.redisearch.client.Client.dropIndex(Client.java:888) ~[jredisearch-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at io.redisearch.client.Client.dropIndex(Client.java:876) ~[jredisearch-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.redis.om.spring.ops.search.SearchOperationsImpl.dropIndex(SearchOperationsImpl.java:176) ~[redis-om-spring-0.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.redis.om.spring.RedisJSONKeyValueAdapter.deleteAllOf(RedisJSONKeyValueAdapter.java:210) ~[redis-om-spring-0.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$delete$4(KeyValueTemplate.java:298) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.delete(KeyValueTemplate.java:296) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.deleteAll(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:210) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy82.deleteAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy82.deleteAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.redis.om.permits.PermitsApplication.lambda$loadTestData$0(PermitsApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the Redis CLI and type `INFO` and also `MODULE LIST`? In the list of modules you should see something like:

`INFO`:

```
# Modules
...
module:name=search,ver=20405,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[]
...
```

`MODULE LIST`:

```
2) 1) "name"
   2) "search"
```

I'm guessing the first thing the Command Line Runner is doing is a `.deleteAll` from the repository, and it seems it can't find the `FT.DROP` command, so you likely don't have the correct version of Redis with the needed modules installed.

You can get one from https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack